# Updating parameters in a javascript function using element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, parameters

I'm trying to update the parameters of a function based on a an element ID. The below code works as intended since the ID parameters are hardcoded.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision_(
        $('#task1'), $('#task2'), $('#task3'), $('#task4')
    ));
}, 200);
```

When I try to compile the parameters dynamically the function isn't working.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    function workerTasks() {
        var task = document.getElementById("worker1").children;
        var tasks = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= task.length - 1; i++) {
            tasks.push($("#" + task[i].id))
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    $('#result').text(collision_(tasks));
}, 200);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED CODE BELOW ---------

I'm pairing this with draggable collision functions that are driven off of the true or false response - but I'm still not able to indicate the array from 'workerTasks' to be used by 'collision_'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#result').text(collision_(workerTasks()));
            console.log(tasks);
      }, 200);
    });

    function workerTasks() {
      var tasks = '';
      $('#worker1 [id^=task]').each(function(i){
        var comma = $('#worker1 [id^=task]').length == i ? '' : ',';
        tasks += $('#' + $(this).attr('id'))  + comma;
      });
      return tasks;
    }

                    function collision_() {
                            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                                    for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
                                            for (var y = 1; y < arguments.length; y++) {
                                                    if (x == y) {
                                                            continue;
                                                    }
                                                    if (collision(arguments[x], arguments[y])) {
                                                            return true;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                                    return false;
                            }
                    }

                    function collision($div1, $div2) {
                        var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
                        var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
                        var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
                        var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(false);
                        var b1 = y1 + h1;
                        var r1 = x1 + w1;
                        var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
                        var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
                        var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
                        var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(false);
                        var b2 = y2 + h2;
                        var r2 = x2 + w2;

                        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1> r2) return false;
                        return true;
                        }
```

Comment: I guess so tasks.push should push an object not a string. Try to remove " "

Comment: you are pushing bunch of strings to `tasks` jquery code dont execute

Comment: @Programmer1228 it should be `tasks.push($("#" + task[i].id))` like this in your loop

Comment: 1st: what is `function_` ??

Comment: Thank you @daremachine and @Nirus! Removing the " " returned the correct string. I've updated the original post. The function_ still doesn't return a value even though "return tasks;" output in a console.log is the same as the original parameters $('#task1'),$('#task2'),$('#task3'),$('#task4'). Thoughts?

Comment: May be there is no need for all this code if you just showing your `function_` code??

Comment: `function_` is literally the worst function name I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should be

```
$('#result').text(function_(workerTasks()));
```

and that workerTasks() function I would move it to outside of your setInterval function.

So it would be

```
function workerTasks() {
   var task = document.getElementById("worker1").children;
   var tasks = [];
   for (i = 0; i <= task.length - 1; i++) {
       tasks.push($("#" + task[i].id))
   }
   return tasks;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(function_(workerTasks()));
}, 200);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately the array returned for 'function_' isn't passing through correctly - even though a console.log shows the array is the same. I'll try to setup a test page to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll post my answer to solve this code issue even if I believe there is no need for all this code if you just showing `function_` content

**1st**: I don't prefer mixing jquery with pure js

**2nd**: There is no mean to save tasks as an array while `function_` not accept array as a parameter

So your code should be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(function_(workerTasks()));
  }, 200);
});
function workerTasks() {
  var tasks = '';
  $('#worker1 [id^=task]').each(function(i){
    var comma = $('#worker1 [id^=task]').length == i ? '' : ',';
    tasks += $('#' + $(this).attr('id'))  + comma;
  });
  return tasks;
}
```

**Update**: After edited the question with the `collision` and `collision_` functions .. See the next demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision_(workerTasks()));
  }, 200);
  
  $('button').on('click' , function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
  });
});
function workerTasks() {
  var tasks = [];
  $('#worker1 [id^=task]').each(function(i){
    tasks.push($('#' + $(this).attr('id')));
  });
  return tasks;
}
function collision_(objArr) {
  if (objArr.length > 1) {
    for (var x = 0; x < objArr.length; x++) {
      for (var y = 1; y < objArr.length; y++) {
        if (x == y) {
           continue;
        }
        if (collision(objArr[x], objArr[y])) {
             return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}


function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(false);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(false);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1> r2){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="worker1">
  <div id="task1">Task 1 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task2">Task 2 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task3">Task 3 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task4">Task 4 <button>X</button></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision_(workerTasks()));
  }, 200);
  
  $('button').on('click' , function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
  });
});
function workerTasks() {
  var tasks = [];
  $('#worker1 [id^=task]').each(function(i){
    tasks.push('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
  });
  return tasks;
}
function collision_(objArr) {
  if (objArr.length > 1) {
    for (var x = 0; x < objArr.length; x++) {
      for (var y = 1; y < objArr.length; y++) {
        if (x !== y) {
          if (collision(objArr[x], objArr[y])) {
               return true;
          }
        }else{
          return false;
        } 
      }
    }
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}


function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $($div1).offset().left;
  var y1 = $($div1).offset().top;
  var h1 = $($div1).outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $($div1).outerWidth(false);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $($div2).offset().left;
  var y2 = $($div2).offset().top;
  var h2 = $($div2).outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $($div2).outerWidth(false);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1> r2){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="worker1">
  <div id="task1">Task 1 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task2">Task 2 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task3">Task 3 <button>X</button></div>
  <div id="task4">Task 4 <button>X</button></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the assist - and the direction of best practices. I'm a beginner, so any tips greatly helps. Even by implementing the code you proposed, the parameters for "function_" aren't working. The "function_" is a bit lengthy - I'll try to setup a test file for reference.

Comment: @Programmer1228 if `function_($('#task1'), $('#task2'), $('#task3'),$('#task4'))` this code works fine with you as you said .. so my code should work .. if not please edit your question with `function_` function

Comment: I added the function for 'function_' (which I admit is a horrible name). I've since changed it to 'collision_'.

Comment: @Programmer1228 updated answer with demo .. I change `arguments.length` and use `collision_(objArr)` and change js inside `.each()` function to get the array of objects .. see the demo and try the code and let me know what is happen?

Comment: @Programmer1228 I added a delete button .. you can remove the element to be just one and you'll return to false

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm now able to run the parameters through as an array - although now since the 'collision_' function uses an array, I'm receiving console.log errors saying '$div1' and '$div2' are undefined for 'collision' function - which makes sense. Obviously if I manually define '$div1' and '$div2' the function works - but the goal would be for '$div1' would be the selected (dragged) element and '$div2' would be any other element in the array that's not '$div1'. Let me know if you have insights. I'll continue to work on it! Thank you again!

Comment: @Programmer1228 updated answer with new demo .. check it .. I don't exactly get your point .. but anyway see the second demo may help